# SOLR and stemming

Tags: solr, stemming

Is there an easy way to simply exclude certain words from stemming in solr?   We have a database full of food items and everytime we search for things like "fried shrimp" it will bring back results like "boiled shrimp served with fries"

For nearly 98% of our search the stemming in all other instances work fine and we want to keep stemming in place.

We just need to omit certain words from the stemming process like "fries" and "fried" so they are unique and not variations of each other.  So that when we search for "fries" it picks up just "fries" but not "fried catfish" or anything with the word fried in it.

Thanks!

Comment: What if you just filter the results after they come back, to verify that the actual word you want is in there?

Comment: thank Greg..prob is we want to provide the most relevant results possible first to the user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory` should protect words from being stemmed. See [this page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Notes_about_solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory) regarding the SnowballPorterStemmer.

Comment: thanks...we followed your link and used the protected.txt file in conjunction with the porterstemmer and it worked perfectly!!